# Use other decorators alongside moto decorator

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, boto, moto

I am trying to use the moto decorator `@mock_sqs` in a test that I also mark with the decorator `@pytest.mark.asyncio`. but when trying to do so the `@mock_sqs` decorators fails to create a mock SQS queue, instead opting to use a real queue which means I get an internal CredentialsNotFountError. Removing the `@pytest.mark.asyncio` decorator fixes the error (but I, of course, need it):

```py
@pytest.mark.asyncio
@mock_sqs
def test_foo(monkeypatch):
   client = setup_mock_client() #create an AWS client
   client.send_message(#....) # CredentialsNotFount
   # ......
```

Comment: Have you tried switching the order around?

Comment: What happen if you change order i.e. `@mock_sqs` first then `@pytest.mark.asyncio`?

Comment: @luk2302 same error

Comment: Can you post the contents of `setup_mock_client`? Moto does not work well with concurrency/multithreading, so I wonder if that's related